# Remove Duplicate Contacts from list based on Duplicate rule defined on Contact Object in apex

Tags: apex

If have a list of Contacts which I need to insert in bulk. This list has duplicate contacts with same First Name, Last Name, email etc. There is a duplicate rule defined on Contact object. Initially, when there are no Contacts present in Contact Object and when try to insert this list, all duplicate contacts will be inserted, because Duplicate rule will not fire on the records which we are inserting in bulk.

Is there a way to figure out if there is a duplicate contact record in the List before inserting them based on Duplicate rule? Because I need to insert only those Contacts which passes Duplicate Rule.

Comment: Doesn't the duplicate rule cause the insert of just those records to fail? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: So, if there are no contacts present in Contact object and if we try to insert Contacts in bulk, then Duplicate rules doesn't fire. Duplicate rules compares what is present in Contact v/s what we are going to insert. If there is nothing present in Contact record and if we try to insert records in bulk then duplicate rules won't fire.

Comment: It should re-evaluate them in every batch of your data load. Also, I believe the Duplicate Management tools come with some sort of monitoring dashboard to find existing dupes. I would recommend you just do the data load and analyze after the fact. If you're really worried about it you could set your data load batch size to 1.

Comment: The bulk data insertion in happening in a batch class. In single batch if we do bulk insertion using list at that time Duplicate rules won't fire. In the next batch, it will definitely run the duplicate rules because now we have some data in Contact object. But the thing is I want to fire Duplicate rule inside the Contacts which are present in list because Batch size is > 1

Comment: Like I said, I think you're going to have to monitor after the fact.